# Hourly gaps in data for a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

Hi Fellow StackOverflowers

I'm really struggling with finding the right approach for this (in my mind) relatively simple Gap-finding problem.
I have a table with hourly datetimes (hourly log file imported to DB).
I need to find the missing hours during a period (lets say april).
So imagine having the following data in DB table [imported_logs]

```
[2018-04-02 10:00:000]
[2018-04-02 11:00:000]
[2018-04-02 12:00:000] 
[2018-04-02 17:00:000]
```

i need the result for april gap analysis to be:

```
[      GAP-BEGIN     ]  [     GAB_END        ]
[2018-04-01 00:00:000]  [2018-04-02 10:00:000] <-- problem
[2018-04-02 13:00:000]  [2018-04-02 17:00:000] <-- can be found using below code
[2018-04-02 18:00:000]  [2018-05-01 00:00:000] <-- problem
```

My problem is mainly finding the start and end ranges, but the following code is helping finding the cap in between available data.

```
    WITH t AS (
      SELECT  *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY zone ORDER BY hourImported)
      FROM  logsImportedTable
      Where hourImported > '2018-04-01' and hourImported < '2018-05-01' and zone = 1
    )  
    SELECT  t1.zone, t1.hourImported as GapStart, t2.hourImported as GapEnd
    FROM    t t1
    INNER JOIN t t2 ON t2.zone = t1.zone AND t2.rn = t1.rn + 1
    WHERE   DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.hourImported, t2.hourImported) > 60
```

which gives me only the result:

```
  [zone] [gap_start              ] [gap_end                ]
  [1   ] [2018-04-02 13:00:00.000] [2018-04-02 17:00:00.000]
```

So basically if no logs has been imported during april at all the current implemetation would show no missing data at all (kinda wrong)

I'm thinking that i need to somehow add some new datapoints just before beginning and end of the april period to somehow get the query to catch the start and end of the month as missing data?
What would you bright guys/girls do?

/Kind regards

Comment: search for: SQL gaps islands

Comment: I have been searching a lot, and therefore is able to find the GAP inside the data. But not the GAPS in non-existing data at the ends of the period (month of april)... That's my problem and i have yet to find a suitable solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this situation, just add the initial and end values, if appropriate:

```
<your query here>
union all
select '2018-04-01 00:00:000', min(lit.hourImported)
from logsImportedTable lit
where lit.hourImported >= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
having min(lit.hourImported) > '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
union all
select '2018-05-01 00:00:000', max(lit.hourImported)
from logsImportedTable lit
where lit.hourImported <= '2018-05-01 00:00:00'
having max(lit.hourImported) > '2018-05-01 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Thx for this - it works almost perfect!
But for months where no data is available it should show the gap as `2018-01-01 00:00:00 to 2018-02-01 00:00:000`
in its current form it will show the min or max of available data overall, like this for july data: `zone_id gap_start gap_end
1 2018-05-31 11:00:00.000 2018-08-01 00:00:00.000`

Comment: @KristianT . . . Just add another `union all` for the entire month.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thx to the great help from @Gordon this is my final solution to the problem. It will give the gaps even if entire month of data is missing and all small gaps within.

```
DECLARE @zone INT = 1, @currentPeriodStart DATETIME = '2018-01-01', 
@currentPeriodEnd DATETIME = '2018-02-01';

WITH t AS (
SELECT  *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY zone_id ORDER BY 
time_of_file_present)
FROM  test
Where time_of_file_present > @currentPeriodStart and time_of_file_present < 
@currentPeriodEnd and zone_id = @zone
)  
SELECT  t1.zone_id, t1.time_of_file_present as gap_start, 
t2.time_of_file_present as gap_end
FROM    t t1
    INNER JOIN t t2 ON t2.zone_id = t1.zone_id AND t2.rn = t1.rn + 1
WHERE   DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.time_of_file_present, t2.time_of_file_present) >60 

union all
select @zone, @currentPeriodStart, min(lit.time_of_file_present)
from test lit
where lit.time_of_file_present >=  @currentPeriodStart
having min(lit.time_of_file_present) >  @currentPeriodStart and 
min(lit.time_of_file_present) < @currentPeriodEnd

union all
select @zone,max(lit.time_of_file_present), @currentPeriodEnd
from test lit
where lit.time_of_file_present <= @currentPeriodEnd
having max(lit.time_of_file_present) < @currentPeriodEnd and 
max(lit.time_of_file_present) > @currentPeriodStart

union all
select @zone,@currentPeriodStart, @currentPeriodEnd
from test lit
having max(lit.time_of_file_present) < @currentPeriodStart or 
max(lit.time_of_file_present) > @currentPeriodEnd
order by gap_start
```